# How to determine if an excel ODBC background query is done refreshing

Tags: perl, vba, excel

I have a perl application which opens an Excel 2010 spreadsheet and runs the RefreshAll command. The spreadsheet has many ODBC queries which each take ~20 minutes to return the results. Because of the number of queries and the time each of them take they must run in the background. I need to be able to determine when all the queries have completed so I can save the spreadsheet. I have tried using the Workbook->Connections->ODBCConnection->Refreshing property to determine this. However this does not work once I have executed the Workbook->RefreshAll command. When I added some debugging code to print out the connection name it returns nothing. However if I do not execute the RefreshAll command I will get a value back for the Connection and I am able to see the value of the refreshing command (0 since it has not been executed yet). I have seen similar posts stating that the queries need to be executed in the foreground. This is not an option as I can not wait 16+ hours for each query to execute one at a time. They must execute in parallel which then they will all be complete within 30 minutes. Here is my code:

```
    $book->RefreshAll;
    # allow the connections to be established
    sleep 10;
    while (1 == 1) {
       foreach my $conn (in $book->{Connections}){
      # Never gets in this loop unless the RefreshAll command is commented out
          &LOG("Found connection $conn->{Name}\n");
          $oc = $conn->{ODBCConnection};
          $refreshing += $oc->{Refreshing};
       }
       &LOG("REFRESH loop has a value of $refreshing\n");
       if ($refreshing == 0) {
          last;
       }
       sleep 30;
    }
```

If someone has an example of how to do this in perl or VBA or another language I can make it work in my code.

Comment: the only way I can think of (at the moment) is [QueryTable.AfterRefresh Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff835922%28v=office.14%29.aspx). However, I'm not sure if will apply in your situation.

Comment: If you have 20-30 Minutes of refreshing data in an excel sheet you should really be looking for a new way to store/retrieve/present your data.

Comment: I agree with that but unfortunately this is a legacy system which I have to work with until such time when the execs open their wallets. That may take some time to convince them that this current process is not the right solution.